# How to use adaptiveThreshold from OpenCV for values larger than 255 (i.e. type CV_8UC1)?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, vector, adaptive-threshold

I want to use the `adaptiveThreshold` function from *OpenCV* in order to determine appropriate, local thresholds for values in a `vector<double>`.

`adaptiveThreshold` is specified in the [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html) as follows:

```
void adaptiveThreshold(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, double maxValue, int adaptiveMethod, int thresholdType, int blockSize, double C)
```

Note that `src` has to be a **Source 8-bit single-channel image** (so the input needs to be of type `CV_8UC1` if I understand correctly, please correct me if I'm wrong here...).

Since my `vector<double>` is not of type `CV_8UC1`, one way to approach this would be to normalize the values within a range of `0` and `255` and then feed the resulting normalized values as a `vector<unsigned char>` into the `adaptiveThreshold` function.

This might look good at first sight, but it comes with a large loss of precision as the values within my original `vector<double>` grow very large and get normalized down to the range of `0` to `255`.

So, I am wondering if there isn't an option to use the `adaptiveThreshold` function for a wider range of values. It seems so unlogical to me that it should only work with values with a max of `255`... It feels like I oversee something quite simple but I can't figure out how to solve the issue...

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but have you quantified how much precision you lose when you normalize your values, and whether it makes an impact on your application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there isn't such an option for a wider range of values. But it is fairly easy to derive a version that takes 'double' values as OpenCV is open source.  Just find the source code of adaptiveThreshold() and change it for your own use.